# htaccess code to web.config

Tags: xml, .htaccess, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to write htaccess rule in windows server 2008 R2.I need to convert this htaccess code to web.config code.I wrote the below code in htaccess file.

```
 <Files feed.xml> 
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml 
 </Files
```